# No Java runtime present, requesting install

Tags: java, eclipse

I have java JDK installed sucessfully in my mac os 10.9 ..

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

But when i try to run eclipse it asks me to jave SE 6 Runtime again !!!

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like eclipse is unable to locate the installed java. You can tell eclipse to point to  this version of java by modifying [eclipse.ini file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Updating_eclipse.ini_on_MacOS)

In eclipse.ini file, we need to add -vm option to point to the java8 location:
See: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

Comment: ![eclipse.init image](http://i.imgur.com/yw6jSpU.png) Nothing happen, open this image .. that's what i did.